# Why does my PyVista plot produce vertical lines of scalars instead of continuous data distribution on my mesh?

Tags: python, visualization, vtk, python-xarray, pyvista

```
import xarray as xr
import geovista as gv
from geovista.pantry import oisst_avhrr_sst
import geovista.theme
import numpy as np
import pyvista as pv
from conversion import to_lonlats


def returnClosest(ds,target):
    
    differences = np.abs(ds - target)
    closest_index = differences.argmin()
    closest_element = ds[closest_index]
    return closest_element





# Load sample data
dataset = xr.open_dataset('temp.nc', decode_times=False)
# print(dataset)

# Extract coordinates and variable values
x = dataset['LON1_4501'].values
y = dataset['LAT'].values
lon,lat=np.meshgrid(x,y)
z = dataset['WATER_TEMP'].values[0, 0, :, :]
mesh=pv.StructuredGrid(lon,lat,z)
plotter=pv.Plotter()

plotter.add_mesh(mesh,scalars=z)
plotter.show()
```

This code shows me a grid with the temperature data plotted in a very weird and irregular manner and I wanted it to be plotted continuous but I cant find a way to do so as I am very new to pyvista

[image]

If I zoom in to this plot, it shows me the scalar distribution in the form of vertical lines and I want it to be continuous

I have plotted in a same way with a different dataset and it shows me the same issue

[image]

dataset link:https://github.com/rajivjha0599/cdf/blob/main/time_series.nc

Comment: Please [edit] your question so that it contains a [mcve]. Currently it has several typos that raise errors. Instead of saying "just choose a file and fix the column names" link to a specific file and fix the column names yourself (hosting data outside Stack Overflow is already frowned upon, but in this case that's not the main issue). And the mesh you're plotting has no scalars, only point data. So when I plot it I get no color variation. When you've made sure your [edit]ed question runs and reproduces your issue, also post a screenshot so that we see what you see.

Comment: Hello, thank you so much for directing me as I'm very new to stack overflow.  I've done the changes and I don't really know how I should provide people with my dataset without an external link.

Comment: This looks like a classic case of C vs F ordering. When assigning your values to the mesh, you may need to do: `z.ravel(order='F')`